# updated : The size of tensor a (64) must match the size of tensor b (512) at non-singleton dimension 1

Tags: deep-learning, pytorch, neural-network, conv-neural-network, fast-ai

Do I need to reshape my input tensor?
I have tried to reduce my input's dinmesion:
`x = x.permute(0,2,1).mean( dim = [1,2], keepdim = True).squeeze(dim= -1)`
however I get
`Given groups=1, weight of size [64, 4, 8], expected input[1, 512, 2] to have 4 channels, but got 512 channels instead`

Do I need to different loss function ? or do I need to custion my input by one hot encodder?
My input is DNA sqeuence and I am trying to predict its  corresponding float value.

Input :

```
def one_hot_encode(seq):
    """
    Given a DNA sequence, return its one-hot encoding
    """
    # Make sure seq has only allowed bases
    allowed = set("ACTGN")
    if not set(seq).issubset(allowed):
        invalid = set(seq) - allowed
        raise ValueError(f"Sequence contains chars not in allowed DNA alphabet (ACGTN): {invalid}")
    # Dictionary returning one-hot encoding for each nucleotide 
    nuc_d = {'A':[1.0,0.0,0.0,0.0],
             'C':[0.0,1.0,0.0,0.0],
             'G':[0.0,0.0,1.0,0.0],
             'T':[0.0,0.0,0.0,1.0],
             'N':[0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0]
             }
    # Create array from nucleotide sequence
    vec=np.array([nuc_d[x] for x in seq])
    return vec 

class SeqDatasetOHE(Dataset):
    '''
    Dataset for one-hot-encoded sequences
    '''
    def __init__(self,
                 df,
                 seq_col='Seq',
                 target_col= target_col
                ):
        # extract the DNA from the appropriate column in the df
        self.seqs = list(df[seq_col].values)
        self.seq_len = len(self.seqs[0])
        
        # one-hot encode sequences, then stack in a torch tensor
        self.ohe_seqs = torch.stack([torch.tensor(one_hot_encode(x),dtype=torch.float, device=device) for x in self.seqs])
    
        self.labels = torch.tensor(list(df[target_col].values),dtype=torch.float, device=device).unsqueeze(1)
        
    def __len__(self): return len(self.seqs)
    
    def __getitem__(self,idx):
        # Given an index, return a tuple of an X with it's associated Y
        # This is called inside DataLoader
        seq = self.ohe_seqs[idx]
        label = self.labels[idx]
        
        return seq, label

## constructed DataLoaders from Datasets.
def build_dataloaders(train_df,
                      test_df,
                      seq_col='Seq',
                      target_col= target_col,
                      batch_size=batch_size_init,
                      shuffle=True
                     ):
 

    # create Datasets    
    train_ds = SeqDatasetOHE(train_df,seq_col=seq_col,target_col=target_col)
    test_ds = SeqDatasetOHE(test_df,seq_col=seq_col,target_col=target_col)

    # Put DataSets into DataLoaders
    train_dl = DataLoader(train_ds, batch_size=batch_size, shuffle=shuffle)
    test_dl = DataLoader(test_ds, batch_size=batch_size)
    
    return train_dl,test_dl
    

train_dl, val_dl = build_dataloaders(train_df, val_df)
```

Model :

```
# import the necessary packages
from torch.nn import Module,Conv1d,Linear,MaxPool1d,ReLU,Dropout

class model_test(nn.Module): # deepcre model  
    def __init__(self,
                 seq_len: int =1000,
                 kernel_size: int = 8,
                 p = 0.25): # drop out value 
        super().__init__()
        self.seq_len = seq_len
        # adjusting window size corresponding to sequence length 
        window_size = int(seq_len*(8/3000))
        # CNN module
        self.conv11 = Conv1d(4,64,kernel_size=kernel_size, padding='same')
        self.relu11 = ReLU()
        self.conv12 = Conv1d(64,64,kernel_size=kernel_size, padding='same')
        self.relu12 = ReLU()
        self.maxpool1 = MaxPool1d(kernel_size=window_size)
        self.Dropout1 = Dropout(p)
        self.fc1 =Linear(seq_len*p, 1)
    
    def forward(self, x: torch.Tensor):
        """Forward pass."""
        x = x.permute(0,2,1)
        print(x.shape)
        x = self.conv11(x)
        x = self.relu11(x)
        x = self.conv12(x)
        x = self.relu12(x)
        x = self.maxpool1(x)
        x = self.Dropout1(x)
        x = self.fc1(x)
        return x
```

Excuting model:

```
# get the sequence length from the first seq in the df
seq_len = len(train_df['Seq'].values[0])
device = 'cuda'

# setting model
model_test = model_test(seq_len)
model_test.to(device)
# setting model to tensor.cuda.double 
model_test.float()

# setting optimizer 
opt = torch.optim.SGD(model_test.parameters(), lr=lr)
opt_func = OptimWrapper(opt=opt)

# Setting learner 
learn = Learner(data, model_test, loss_func=nn.MSELoss(), metrics=accuracy)
learn.opt = OptimWrapper(opt=opt)
```

Error :

```
RuntimeError: The size of tensor a (64) must match the size of tensor b (512) at non-singleton dimension 1
```